# Determine for what values of $a$ the matrix is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Let $A \in M_{3 \times 3} \mathbb{R}$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$ such that:
$$A= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & a & a\\ 
-1 & 1 & -1\\ 
1 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$$
Determine for what values of $a$ the matrix is diagonalizable. For those values, find a matrix $Q$ such that $Q^{-1}AQ$ is diagonal.

So first I find the characteristic polynomial to find its roots, but it is $\lambda ^{3}-4 \lambda^{2}+5\lambda -2a-2$ and I absolutely get stuck there. I can't get any roots from that polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $\lambda ^3-4\lambda ^2+5\lambda-2$, whose roots are $1$ and $2$ (and $2$ is a simple root). So, all that is left is to find the dimension of the eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Why do you say all if left is to find the dimension of the eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue 1? Why ignore the eigenvalue 2?

Comment: A matrix is diagonalizable iff for all eigenvalues the algebraic and the geometric multiplicities coincide. If the eigenvalue is simple, then the geometric and the algebraic multiplicity always coincide and thus we don't need to consider that case.

Comment: By the way, $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if $a=0$.